# Trying to create an error checking method so counter doesn't decrement when counter is at 0

Tags: java, class, methods, error-handling

I'm trying to create a custom Counter class and CounterDemo program for the following instructions, but I'm not sure how to go about error checking (tried writing a method called counterOK that doesn't work) for making sure the error message appears if the counter attempts to decrement from zero. I think I also need to write a method for resetting the value to zero, like the error message says. Shouldn't I be able to just reset it using the Counter method I wrote?

Instructions:
Write a counter class in its own file. This will allow your counter to be used by any program.

The counter must be able to increment and decrement by one. It must never go below zero. toString and equals must be implemented and
tested correctly. System.out.println("”+c1) must work and if(c1.equals(c2)) must work
where c1 and c2 are instances of your counter. Include an override of the default constructor that sets the counter to zero and a constructor
that allows you to set the count.

Write a test program that tests all the features of the counter. See my farkleberry example in course documents.

This assignment tests your understanding of the material in the text. It also provides a template for future assignments. It is designed to
provide you with the basic tools to write commercial classes which are written in separate files and always include toString and equals. It is
also an example of how programmers test their classes prior to releasing them.

```
public class Counter {

    private int count;  //local counting variable

    public Counter()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    public void setCounter(int newCount)
    {
        count = newCount;
    }

    public int getCounter()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void increment1 ()
    {
        count++;
    }

    public void decrement1 ()
    {
        count--;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "" + count;
    }

    public boolean equals(Counter c)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        if (this.getCounter() == c.getCounter())
        {
            result = true;
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean counterOK(int check)
    {
        boolean result = true;
        if (check > 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
            else
                return false;

    }
}

public class CounterDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //initiate objects
        Counter c1 = new Counter(), c2 = new Counter();

        //show initial state of counters
        System.out.println("Initial state");
        System.out.println("Counter1 is at " + c1.toString());
        System.out.println("Counter2 is at " + c2.toString());
        if (c1.equals(c2))
            System.out.println("Counter1 equals Counter2.");
        else
            System.out.println("Counter1 does not equal Counter2");

        c1.decrement1();
        if (c1.counterOK(c1))
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error - attempted to subtract 1 Counter from 0 Counter.\n" + "Number of Counter reset to 0.");
        System.out.println(c1.toString());
    }
}
```

Possible Example Output:

```
This program creates and uses Counters

Initial state  
counter1 is at 0.  
counter2 is at 0.  
counter1 equals counter2.  

Error - Attempted to subtract 1 Counter from 0 Counter.  
Number of Counter reset to 0.  

State after first test  
counter1 is at 1.  
counter2 is at 0.  
counter1 does not equal counter2.  

State after second test  
counter1 is at 2.  
counter2 is at 2.  
counter1 equals counter2.  

Process completed.
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Your equals method is not an override of the equals method of class [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: I'm trying to output the error message "Error - Attempted to subtract 1 Counter from 0 Counter. Number of Counter reset to 0." for when the main class attempts to decrement 1 from 0. From there, I think I can fill in the rest, but I'm not sure how to output that message. Do I use some kind of error checking method that outputs that string when checking if the counter is at 0? Or can I not do that if I'm passing an int (0) to the method and it can't return a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply not decrement below zero by checking.

```
public void decrement1 () {
    if (count==0) {
        System.out.println("Error- Attempted to subtract 1 Counter from 0 Counter. Number of Counter reset to 0." );
        return;
    }
    count--;
}
```

From reading the instructions I don't think you need to display an error, simply handle the error and reset to zero.

Also, you missed the part of the instructions which asks for this constructor:

```
public Counter(int initialCount) {
    if (initialCount < 0) {
        count = 0;
    } else {
        count = initialCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do need to output "Error- Attempted to subtract 1 Counter from 0 Counter. Number of Counter reset to 0." Thank you the second constructor you recommended. Is it to reset it to zero after it attempts to decrement 1 from 0 after the initial test, where the values of c1 and c2 are both 0 at that point? But how do I return a string from an error checking method if I'm passing an integer to it? When I tried to write a boolean method `public boolean counterOK() if (count < 0) return "Error -Attempted..." else return true` that returned a string, I got an error with incompatible data types.

Comment: If you only need to print the Error message, send it to System.out. I ammended the decrement function above to show how to print the error.

Comment: If this answer satisfies your question, then accept the answer @1lynnsey